# Laravel Nova add Category by a modal on a Product create/update page

Tags: laravel-nova

I am searching for a user interface solution and wonder if the following can be made and how.

For example i have a create productpage and on that page we have a dropdown with categories. I want to add a category which is not in the dropdown via a modal. After the insertion i want to update the dropdown and selected the inserted cartegory.

Is that possible and how can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: Nope i mean a modal popup

Comment: I mean something like this. Modal to add a category. https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/525

Comment: If you want to do something like that in index page, it should be using nova Action.If you want, i can write sample code for that.

Comment: Have you tried using Nova action or you need an example?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two alternative solutions using 2 different packages. You can choose any of it.

1. using [gkermer/nova-text-auto-complete](https://packagist.org/packages/gkermer/nova-text-auto-complete)

   ```
    TextAutoComplete::make('Category')->items(function($search) {
       return Category::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
           ->get()
           ->pluck('name');
       }),
   ```
2. Using [select-or-text](https://github.com/0x15f/select-or-text)

   ```
   \Lynndigital\SelectOrCustom\SelectOrCustom::make('Category')->options(Category::all()->pluck('name')->all());
   ```

Now, on Model saving event, in listener, you can get this value save it to your database and get the last inserted id and use as foreign key for products